# Question is about Kramnik Topalov how come there's an answer in general?

Tags: discussion, answers

[How do Kramnik and Topalov indicate a resignation when they play together?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12582/how-do-kramnik-and-topalov-indicate-a-resignation-when-they-play-together/)

The question:

> Which raises the question - how do they go about resigning when playing each other without creating confusion about their intention?

There's no indication that I see that asks how players in general do this.

How is one allowed to answer in generally eg

> Knocking over your king has always been a perfectly acceptable way of resigning.

?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, the question says:

> how do they go about resigning when playing each other without creating confusion about their intention?

and not (what the answer is implying):

> how *could* they go about resigning when playing each other without creating confusion about their intention?

Still, that's so close to the original; what harm does it cause to leave the answer like it is? The score says enough: the other answer is much better. And we don't edit out the bottom half of it because it asks and answers another different question.